# How can I get layer type in pycaffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Is it possible at all to get each layer's type (e.g: Convolution, Data, etc) in pycaffe? 
I searched the examples provided, but I couldn't find anything. currently I'm using layers name to do my job which is extremely bad and limiting .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy!

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/net.prototxt', '/path/to/weights.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)

# get type of 5-th layer
print "type of 5-th layer is ", net.layers[5].type
```

To map between layer names and indices you can use this simple trick:

```
idx = list(net._layer_names).index('my_layer')
print "The index of \'my_layer\' is ", idx, " and the type is ", net.layers[idx].type
```

Comment: I'm getting 'ValueError: 'data' is not in list' when I want to use your second snippet of code for mapping layer names and their indexes. whats wrong?

Comment: @Coderx7 is it possible you do not have a layer named `"data"` in your net?

Comment: I used it inside a for loop which reads layer names directly from net : 
https://paste.ee/p/Z1RZg   

I'm currently doing this:  
https://paste.ee/p/g4Llm

Comment: @Coderx7 you are confusing `blob` names and `layer` names: `blob` names are the arguments of `"top"`/`"bottom"`s while layer names are the arguments of `"name"`. For instance, you may have a `"Data"` **layer** named `"data"` producing **blobs** `"data"` and `"label"`. So you have a **blob** named `"label"` but no layer with that name.

Comment: @Coderx7 you might find the python function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208380/1714410) helpful to understand the difference between blobs and layers and how to access them correctly.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much for the clarification. :)