# Getting pycaffe layer name or blob type

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I have some CNN called `net` for which I'd like to know the type of the blob or the name of the layer.

For example, I can easily access the blob name and the subsequent blob:

```
for blob in net.blobs:
    print(blob)
    net.blobs[blob]...
```

Or, I can access the layer type:

```
for x in range(len(net.layers)):
    print(net.layers[x].type)
```

Is there anyway to access this information like:

```
net.blobs[blob].type
```

or,

`net.layers[x].name`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blob does not have `type`. It's a blob: a container for N-dimensional data. You may look for `net.blobs[blob].data.shape` for its `shape`, or look for `net.blobs[blob].diff` for computed gradients (if you backprop the gradients...)

Layers' names are stored in `net._layer_names`. You can get the index of a layer by `idx = list(net._layer_names).index('my_layer')`.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995977/1714410) for more info.