# Converting Caffe caffemodel weight files to TensorFlow weight files

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

My team has spent several months training a Caffe model but now we're looking at converting to Tensorflow and we don't want to spend several months retraining.

How can I convert our caffemodel weight files to TensorFlow weight files?

I've tried [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) but it won't work for Caffe models that have layers with more than one top.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), but you can use [this python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208380/1714410) to "dump" the trained caffe weights to python-readable numpy arrays. I would expect TF to have a functionality to init its weights from numpy arrays - this method might not be automatic or trivial, but you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get from caffe-tensorflow? If this is just a validation check, you can disable it. You can also try to enforce the tool to load the weights through `load_using_pb` function. ([transformers.py](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow/blob/0c5bf53817f89c7e4581ad6b738a4bb19eea96b3/kaffe/transformers.py) / DataInjector / load function)

Comment: Hi @rkellerm , If you're still out there, please reply to this. I highly need your help!

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - still here, hope I can help (But my focus has changed so not sure that I have the relevant knowledge)

Comment: Am glad that you replied. So am using caffe-tensorflow to convert a pose estimation caffe model to tensorflow pb model. Every layer has been converted succesfully except the final layer(Output layer). It's saying that,** AssertionError: Mconv7_stage6 is not in graph.**

Comment: @AdityaNikhil I'm not familiar with this error, but if I understood correctly you try to convert CMU's OpenPose -- it has already a working TF version: https://github.com/infocom-tpo/tf-openpose. Didn't dig into the code, but they succeeded to convert the original Caffe weights. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @rkellerm, thanks for the link but i need a hand pose model to estimate hand poses. Se there's only one caffe model out there to do this, https://www.kaggle.com/changethetuneman/openpose-model. Please let me know if you can find a tensorflow version of this...