# How to get the output shape of a layer via Pycaffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

The title already contains the full question: How can I get the output shape of a given layer of a Caffe model using Pycaffe?

I have a `caffe.Net()` object and now I want the output shape of a specific layer in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the layer name, you can get its index via:

```
l_idx = list(net._layer_names).index(my_layer_name)
```

Once you have `l_idx`, you can get its outputs (aka `"top"`s):

```
tops = [(net._blob_names[bi], net.blobs[net._blob_names[bi]].data.shape) 
        for bi in list(net._top_ids(li))]
```

for each `"top"` you can get the informtation

```
for tn in tops:
  print "output name {} has shape {}".format(tn, net.blobs[tn].data.shape)
```

A more detailed example on how to access net's structure via pycaffe interface can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208380/1714410).