# Save the weights for a specific layer, not only visualize on Caffe

Tags: caffe

I have this network loaded into net `net = caffe.Net('mobilenet_v2_deploy.prototxt', caffe.TEST)`. Then, to save the weights of this layer I can do `net.save('mymodel.caffemodel')` But, how could I ***save*** only a ***particular layer's weights***? I know that to visualize `conv1` layer's weights I can do (1) `net.params['conv1'][0].data` but, this just outputs on the command line some text, it does not save a caffemodel-like file.

(1) Outputs something such as: (does not save a file)

```
array([[[[-0.1010774 ]],
        [[-0.03301976]],
        [[ 0.19851202]],
        ...,}
```

Example of the prototxt file

```
"name: "MOBILENET_V2"
#  transform_param {
#    scale: 0.017
#    mirror: false
#    crop_size: 224
#    mean_value: [103.94,116.78,123.68]
#  }
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    bias_term: false
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "msra"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208380/1714410) to convert the weights to numpy and then [`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) only the weights that you care about.